# Subtotal error on calculated field in a Reporting Services Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've got a Reporting Services report that has two row groups: Category and SubCategory.  For columns it has LastYearDataA, ThisYearDataA, LastYearDataB, ThisYearDataB.

I added two columns (one for A and one for B) to handle an expression calculation (to show a percentage different from LastYear to ThisYear for each).  That's working. The problem comes in the SubTotal for each category.  The raw numbers are totaling correctly.  If SubCat1 has 10//5 for LastYear/ThisYear A, and SubCat2 has 5//1, then I get 15/5 for the totals.  But I get the percentage reported in the total column as "50%", matching SubCat1.  Percentages for each Subcategory are being calculated correctly (according to my backup math, anyway).  But the sub total % always matches the first SubCategory in the group.  Is this impossible to do in Reporting Services 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never got to the bottom of this.  I changed my sproc to return category totals and a grand total along with all the data.  This is going to come up again, so I'll keep looking and maybe I'll discover why with more searching.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is change the value of the detail field in the Matrix. So where you have:

```
=Fields!FieldName.Value
```

Change it to:

```
=Sum(Fields!FieldName.Value)
```

When it's displaying a value in a normal row or column, I guess it just sums the one value, so it doesn't change it, but when it's in a subtotal column, it sums them like you wanted. Counter-intuitive I know. I had to search to figure it out too.

Comment: Well, I got laid off so I can't go back and check this.  From what I remember, and it's very possible I'm remembering incorrectly, Reporting Services was already doing sums on the fields in question.